# Cell displaying a date instead of value

Tags: excel, vba

I need to log the date and current values of four cells. In the loop below it keeps printing a date instead of two of the values like so:

```
Date      DRI_1        DRI_2     DRI_3  PRI

3/1/2016  33.33333333  8.75      12     54.08333333

3/1/2016  2/2/1900     8.75      12     54.08333333

3/1/2016  33.33333333  1/8/1900  12     54.08333333

3/1/2016  33.33333333  8.75      12     54.08333333
```

The dates occupy the second line directly after the date and the third line after the value after the date.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copypaste()
'
' Copypaste Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+p
'
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim this_date As Date
    Dim ls As Boolean

    i = 2
    j = 24
    k = 0
    this_date = DateValue(Now)
    ls = True

    Do While ls = True

        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j).Value) = True Then

            For k = 1 To 3
                Cells(i, j + k).Value = Cells(2, 19 + k).Value
            Next k

            Cells(i, 28).Value = Cells(3, 20).Value

            Cells(i, j).Value2 = this_date

            ls = False

        Else
            ls = True
        End If

        i = i + 1

        If i > 1000 Then
            ls = False
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

It seems to be an isolated issue with my code!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies it was the formatting of the cells, they had a date in them previously and all I needed to do was to copy a regular cell to those positions and it stopped!

Apologies for any one's time that is wasted!

Comment: To avoid this problem in future, you can set the number format of a cell using VBA. So, for example, after the line `Cells(i, j + k).Value = Cells(2, 19 + k).Value` you could have a line saying `Cells(i, j + k).NumberFormat = "General"` to set the format of the cells you have pasted values into to general, or any other number format as you see fit.

Comment: Post as an answer, not a comment.  I would say NumberFormat is the correct answer, not extra copy and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

If DRI_1 and DRI_2 are columns B and C then you could format them as general using

```
Range("B:C").NumberFormat = "General"
```